# Detect newly connected keyboard inside privileged container via libinput

Tags: linux, keyboard, docker

I'm running a GUI app inside Docker on Raspberry Pi. I need to use keyboard in that app.

So far I got to the point, where I run the container as privileged and I mount /run/udev to it which enables detection of the keyboard even when it's disconnected and reconnected again.

```
docker run -d --privileged -v /run/udev:/run/udev:ro <image>
```

Because it's privileged, if I exec into the container, I can see the keyboard devices:

```
ls /dev/input
by-id  by-path  event0  event1  event2  event3  event4  event5  mice  mouse0  mouse1
```

However, if I first start the container with no keyboard connected and **then** connect the keyboard, these devices won't show up in the container and I can't use the keyboard:

```
ls /dev/input
event0  mice    mouse0
```

Is there a way to make it detect the keyboard in this case? I don't wanna restart the container, I need it to work on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just tried to mount /dev/input directly and it just worked!

```
docker run -d --privileged -v /dev/input:/dev/input:ro -v /run/udev:/run/udev:ro <image>
```